# Power of time varying centripetal force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

In regards to this question,

> A particle of mass $m$ is moving a circular path with constant radius $r$ such that it's centripetal acceleration is varying with time $t$ as $a_c = k^2 r t^2$ where k is constant. Find the power delivered

So, I took the time integral of the centripetal acceleration and dotted that with the acceleration but I got the wrong answer

i.e : $$v_r = k^2 r \frac{t^3}{3}$$

and I multiplied that by the acceleration and mass

However, my answer is wrong..

The correct solution involves finding the tangent velocity and multiplying by that by centripetal force. This makes no sense to me as the dot product of two perpendicular vectors should be zero

Bonus: If the object is in circular motion why would it need a time varying centripetal force?

Comment: I think you have misinterpreted the solution. Can you please verify it?

Comment: Work is done on the particle only by *Tangential Forces* , as *Radial Forces* are perpendicular to v.

Comment: This is a previous year JEE question, the solutions are available online on many other forums. Please keep in mind that this is not a forum for check-my-work/homework-type questions.

Comment: I do agree with @wavion

Comment: https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/a-particle-of-mass-m-is-moving-in-a-circular1/

They have taken the tangential velocity

Tangential velocity dotted with centripetal acceleration should be 0

Comment: @DDD4C4U They don't do that... They said $P = F \cdot v$ where $F$ is the _tangential_ force acting on the particle (which is why it's calculated from $F = m a_{t}$; not $F = m a_{c}$)

Comment: @DDD4C4U are u still looking for it's solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a circular track on which a body is moving. Let us just assume that its velocity (tangential, of course) is increasing. If it is increasing, then, for the object to maintain a constant radius (as required by the question), the centripetal acceleration should also increase.

So, the need for a time-varying centripetal force is justified if the tangential velocity is increasing. But the actual change is in the tangential velocity, so, a tangential force is being applied. And it is the power of this tangential force that you must find. (or at least that is what makes sense).

I think that you have misunderstood the solution. It might have been a dot product between tangential force and tangential velocity.

Comment: https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/a-particle-of-mass-m-is-moving-in-a-circular1/

Comment: They have not taken dot product between tangential velocity and centripetal acceleration. Rather, they seem to have taken tangential acceleration and its dot product with tangential velocity, hence the angle is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

From the centripetal acceleration you get the tangential velocity. From that you get the tangential acceleration and force. The tangential force times the tangential velocity gives the power.